# Retorno API Laravel json

Tags: php, json, api, laravel-5

Estou com um seguinte problema, fiz uma `API` e me retorna um `array`:

```
"id": 1,
"email": "lucas@mail.com",
"senha": "lucas123",
"created_at": "2018-02-15 16:48:12",
 "updated_at": "2018-02-15 16:48:12"`
```

e gostaria que só retornasse 3 campos `id`,`email` e `senha`

**Método:**

```
public function index() 
{ 
    $contas = login::all(); 
    return response()->json(['contas'=>$contas], 200); 
}
```

Comment: Por favor pode colocar o código do `controller`, a imagem dificulta muito.

Comment: Opa sim! vou mandar so o metodo index pode ser ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É só selecionar com o método [select](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#selects) o que precisa:

```
login::select('id', 'email', 'senha')->get();
```

Código completo:

```
public function index() 
{ 
    $contas = login::select('id', 'email', 'senha')->get();
    return response()->json(['contas'=>$contas], 200); 
}
```

<sup>***Referencia:*** [Laravel - Selects](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#selects)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

**Para que você consiga retornar um objeto e não um array, basta:**

```
public function index() 
{ 
    $contas = login::select('id', 'email', 'senha')->get();
    return response()->json(Arr::first($contas), 200); 
}
```

Veja que no caso é usado um Helper do próprio Laravel que pega o primeiro item da resposta vinda do select. Assim quando passamos isso para o response o retorno será um objeto e não mais um array.

**Para usar os helpers do Laravel adicione:**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
```

**IMPORTANTE:**

```
Arr::first()
```

Como informado retorna o primeiro item de um array, se você precisa retornar uma Collection, ou mais de um item como objeto na mesma resposta o processo informado não funcionará.